# How can I setup PHPUnit for a CodeIgniter project with HMVC

Tags: php, phpunit, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-hmvc

I have a project in CodeIgniter 2.1.3 using [HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc). How can I setup PHPUnit for a CodeIgniter project with HMVC?